# ViewPager Lag using FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to build an application made of 10 Fragments using ViewPager along with FragmentStatePagerAdapter (and `setOffScreenPageLimit(3)`). There are 5 Fragment which are going to perform realtime updates modifying TextViews, Graphs and ProgressBars (so they're always performing actions on the MainUi thread). In this scenario, when I slide between Fragments the animation is very laggy (takes 1 to 2 seconds to change fragment when I see them for the first time, then it takes less but there are always lags).

What I'm asking is: how can I improve the smoothness of transactions?

Should I change my way to implement fragments (using FragmentManager instead of ViewPager), slow down the animation or perform some sort of operations before the sliding?

I have not so much experience in Android so any help is appreciated.

Comment: did your fragment contain images taken from drawables? if yes then put them in drawables-nodpi folder

Comment: Yes, I've already did that

Comment: What is the slowest update? Graph? How much does it take?

Comment: The graph is updated along with TextViews every second and as far as I know it's the slowest update among the views

Comment: Why don't you first show a fragment and then, if the user didn't move to next page, would update the page? So that not write everything in `onCreateView`.

Comment: Good point, I've tried to implement that kind of behaviour but it doesn't work properly, maybe something is missing in the way I did that.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I've found a solution consisting of the incrementation of `setOffScreenPageLimit` argument.

Comment: In this case your can simply use `FragmentPagerAdapter`, it keeps in memory all fragments.

Comment: I already tried FragmentPagerAdapter intead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter and it didn't solve lags. As I said in the answer, incrementing the argument of that function is the way I found to reduce lags and I still don't understand why it works like that.